# Remove from Destination array all occurrences of all characters that occur in Source Array

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two character arrays a[] and b[], remove from b[] all occurrences of all characters that occur in array a[]. You need to do this in-place i.e. without using an extra array of characters.
E.g.:

```
Input: a[] = [‘G’, ‘O’]          
Input  b[] = [‘G’, ’O’, ’O’, ’G’, ’L’, ’E’] 

Output: b[] = [‘L’, ‘E’]
```

Code :

```
public class ReplaceCharacterArray{         
       public static void main(String args[]){        
          char a[] = [‘G’, ‘O’]         
          char b[] = [‘G’, ’O’, ’O’, ’G’, ’L’, ’E’]     

         //to replace all the occurences of all the characters of     
         //a[] array in b[] array we have below logic.     

          for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){     
             for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){     
                  if(b[j] == a[i]){     
                    //im stuck here how to proceed      
             }     
          }
```

Comment: im really stuck with this for a long time.please help me

Comment: Please format your code properly using the 1010110 button

Comment: @aioobe: could you please help me now to refine this code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove elements "in place" in Java arrays. They have fixed length. That is, in your example you'll have to return a new array, since you can't change the length of the `b` array.

Here are some pointers for you:

- Maintain a write-index for the `b` array (left of this index, you have only characters not present in `a`).
- Iterate through the `b` array
- While the current character is contained in `a`, step forward
- Swap current character (not contained in `a`) with the character at the write-index
- Increment the write-index, and continue from there.

Use for instance `Arrays.copyOfRange` to return the part of the array to the left of the write-index.

---

Regarding your update:

- Arrays are not written using `[` and `]` and characters are not written using `‘`, change them to `{`, `}` and `'`.
- Having a helper method with the signature `boolean arrayContains(char[] arr, char c)` will make it easier to write the algorithm
- If you follow my approach, you will also benefit from having a helper method `void swap(char[] arr, int index1, int index2)`.

Comment: Aioobe,question is same as asked

Comment: Updated my answer. The "least wrong" approach is probably to (when you're done) return a sub-sequence of the cleaned up array.

Comment: You need to do this in-place i.e. without using an extra array of characters.

Comment: Right... that's what I suggest in my answer. Keep swapping the elements in the `b` array so that you collect the "bad characters" in the end. Then finally return the left part of the array.

Comment: im not getting it....can post the code please

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't help you since you still wouldn't have done your homework ;)

Comment: @aioobe: Your solution doesn't preserve the order of the remaining elements.  Don't know if that is a problem though.

Comment: plzzzz i have posted my partial code.please refine it

Comment: edit your question and put your partial code there...

Comment: @JeremyP, I just implemented it and it keeps it in order....

Comment: can u plese post the code.unable to proceed further aioobe...

Comment: Make an attempt to implement the two helper methods: `swap` and `contains`. If you update your answer with those methods, I'll help you with the rest.

Comment: @aioobe: you are right.  I misread your algorithm at first.

Comment: Can anyone of you please post the entire working code.

Comment: Have you tried to implement swap and contains with the signatures I described in my answer?

Comment: @aioobe,@Elite is away,Could you help me with the final part since im unable to remove the NULL Appended characters.

Comment: @Deepak, sure. I have time. Make an attempt to implement the two helper methods: swap and contains. If you update your answer with those methods, I'll help you with the rest.

Comment: @aioobe,I dont know the answer for this question so im asking you people.Can you please post the source code for this,Im a newbie to Java and dataStructures and algorithms.

Comment: Well, if you can't implement a basic `swap` method and a basic `contains` method I think the assignment you posted is kind of "out of your league". I'll give you a few hints for the `swap` and `contains`: The swap method can be implemented with 3 lines: 1) Store the value of `arr[i]` in a temporary variable, 2) assign `a[j]` to `a[i]`, 3) store the value of the temporary variable in `a[j]`. `contains` can also be implemented with three lines: 1) loop through the elements in the array. 2) if the element matches the searched element, return true 3) otherwise (below the loop) return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about like this

Iterate the loop a, that is 2 times and 
In each iteration, perform the copare that value exists in the b[] array, 
if yes delete that. Continue that until you iterate the array b[] completely.

So that in the end you will have b[] array only with the other elements which is not in the array a[].

I hope this will help you to complete your work.

Comment: harui can you please post the code....

Comment: @Deepak, it's you who supposed to be posting code for us to help you (not the other way around).

Comment: Elite i have written the partial code,can you help me in refining it further.

Comment: plzzzz i have posted my partial code.please refine it

Comment: @Deepak, can you refine your question with your code? I can't read code here...

Comment: i have posted the code in question,Please help me

Comment: @BuhakeSindi need java answer for this question.i have posted my partial answer in the question

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in your code,

- Arrays don't start and end with `[` and `]` respectively. They start and end with `{` and `}` respectively.
- Characters are enclosed with `'` only.
- You will have to keep the state of your iterations (in my case I kept the indexing state and the state of to know whether the character in `b` exists in `a`).
- Have a `remove(char[] array, char characterToRemove)` and pass the `b[]` and it's respective character to remove to complete the flow.

---

**Update** without using `String`, `StringBuffer`, or any libraries, this is what works....

**Warning** the array `b` **never** gets reduced (it gets appended with `NULL` character). That I will leave it for you to crack.

```
/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 * 
 */
public class ReplaceCharacterArray {
    public static boolean containsCharacter(char character, char[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == character) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char a[] = {'G', 'O'};
        char b[] = {'G', 'O', 'O', 'G', 'L', 'E'};
        //to replace all the occurences of all the characters of a[] array in b[] array we have below logic.

        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (index < b.length) {
            while (ReplaceCharacterArray.containsCharacter(b[index], a)) {
                System.arraycopy(b, index + 1, b, 0, b.length - index - 1);
                count++;
            }

            index++;
        }

        for (int i = (b.length - count); i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i]= '\0';
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plese the post the java code for this atleast.Im new to data structures....please help provided will be appreciated.

Comment: Elite.Plese the post the java code for this atleast.Im new to data structures....please help provided will be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post the entire JAVA CODE

Comment: Thanks Elite,i will analyse and come back with few more clarifications.

Comment: @@Elite NULL gets appended as told by you,hmmmm there is a bug in this program.The NULL bug,how do i crack that...can u suggest some hints\suggestions\advice me on lines of java

Comment: @Deepak, it's not a bug....It's me who deliberately did that to fit the criteria.

Comment: @Elite,what about the NULL that gets appended.how do i remove that,any pointers Please? (Warning the array b never gets reduced (it gets appended with NULL character). That I will leave it for you to crack. ) The final solution should be b[] = {'L','E'}..Please help me finally

Comment: @Deepak, then what have you done?

Comment: @Elite,Im trying to figure out how to remove the NULL thingy,but i dont know how to proceed.Im out of ideas.Could you help me

Comment: @Elite,Need your help on this,Im confused... :-((

Comment: @Elite,Could you help me in removing those appended Null Characters.i havent got any idea yet

Comment: @Deepak, use Arrays.copyOfRange as suggested by aioobe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since this is a homework 3rd party library's may not be allowed.Any way i'll just post a code using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
 char[] removeChars(char a[],char b[])
 {
    return  CharMatcher.anyOf(new String(b)).removeFrom(new String(a)).toCharArray();    
 }
```

**UPDATE:**(check this sample,it's one way to solve)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class CharReplace{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
char a[] = "GOOGLE".toCharArray();
char b[] = "GO".toCharArray();
BitSet charToRemove=new BitSet();
for(char c:b)
 charToRemove.set(c);
StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
for(char c:a)
 if(!charToRemove.get(c))
  str.append(c);
b=str.toString().toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

}

}
```

Comment: And you introduced Guava, that's a straight fail!

Comment: @Elite could you please post the source code....im really helpless i dont know what contents i have to write for this code.

Comment: Result should be  b[] = {'L','E'}                      im getting b[] = [L,E] which is invalid